# count the total counts of cell per days

Tags: excel

I am trying to find out the total number of order made in a day.
My data is like this :-

```
Date      | Time     | Product | Unit Sold
7/24/2018  10:45:59    Fries       1
7/24/2018  16:45:59    Fries       1
7/25/2018  12:45:59    Fries       1
7/25/2018  11:45:59    Fries       1
7/25/2018  1:45:59     Fries       1
7/25/2018  1:45:59     Fries       1
```

Now here you can see the count of 7/24/2018 is 2 , 7/25/2018 is 4 .. 
I can manually filter and select all column and just copy the count from bottom bar. 
but the problem is I have  calculate of about 3 months of about 10 different branches. 
I did googled up and found out about COUNTIF . and here what I tried

```
=COUNTIFS(range,">="&date1,range,"<="&date2)
```

But it returns me #N/A
Can anyone help me on here?

Comment: What are `range`, `date1` and `date2` in your formula? Are these named ranges, or have you simply used these to try and show your formula in a more readable format? Please [edit] your post to make this clear, and include the actual formula if those references aren't named ranges.

Comment: Sidenote: You have googled about `COUNTIF` but are using `COUNTIFS`. If you really only are interested in orders on ONE particular day, you can just use `COUNTIF`.

Comment: The formula is fine, any case it may return 0 but never #n/a. Are you using some sort of Vlookup() or match() for date1 or date 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is very simple, and can done with a little focus.

Step 1: Make sure the dates in date column are in the same format as with your system date. If yes then move to step 2, if not, Select date column -> then goto **Data tab** in Excel ribbon -> Under data tools you will find **Text to columns** -> Click that and convert the Dates to your system date format. move to Step 2

Step 2: 
The formuala you mentioned

```
 =COUNTIFS(range,">="&date1,range,"<="&date2)
```

I am assuming is an example and real code should look something like this unless you are using Names for ranges

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,">="&B9,A2:A7,"<="&B10)
```

OR a better version would be

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D7,A2:A7,">="&B9,A2:A7,"<="&B10)
```

since this formula will actually sum up the **Unit Sold** column instead of date column. Example attached in image below. Enjoy.

[sumif and countif example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkcqS.png)